# I am trying to install WordPress & Joomla on the same server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla, installation

I am trying to install WordPress & Joomla on the same server but when I do, I get a an error when trying to get to the wordpress blog. I had Joomla installed in the root directory, and I put wordpress in a sub folder (root/wordpress). When I try to go to joomlasite.com/wordpress, it just returns to the homepage. I know Joomla is redirecting it in the htaccess file, but I need to figure out how to stop it from doing that. Please help!

I tried adding this to the joomla htaccess file as seen in a similar post, but it doesn't work.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess file in /wordpress have `RewriteEngine off`. Then you should be able to log in to the WordPress admin and setup permalinks which will overwrite your .htaccess with what's needed.